# WrapPanel for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to add a WrapPanel to my app, up to now I found that WrapPanel is only available through SilverLight Toolkit here http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases

I've downloaded it and installed it, but now what do I do?

I assumed that a reference needed to be added but I can't think of what to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll. The `WrapPanel` control is in the **Microsoft.Phone.Controls** namespace.

In your page/user control, add the following XML namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Then you can add instances of `<toolkit:WrapPanel />` in your XAML.