# C# Silverlight for WindowsPhone --> How can i insert a table with 99 text elements ?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to make an application with multiples of nine. You must think at a number, do some operations , and at the end u must look up the text corresponding to the resultNumber in a special table with elements from 1 to 99 , and these elements will have a text unde each of them. I need some help for inserting this table in my application. Thanks !

Comment: Do you have at drawing showing how it should look like? Has your table only one column? How should a cell look like? Give as an example the content of the first three cells (an integer and a text?)

Comment: The table has 99 cells , 9 columns. Each cell has an number , and under it , a random text that i will write . The numbers of cells will be ascending, from 1 to 99.    Example :   first cell will have number 1 and under it the text  " Car " , second cell number 2 and under it text "Clock" , etc.... .  And after i will insert this table in my application , i must use some numbers with the text under it , from this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `ListBox` (or an `ItemsControl` if you don't need selection of items) with an `ItemsPanelTemplate` being a `WrapPanel`. This way you can simply use data binding and have a layout looking as a grid.

First the ListBox with a [WrapPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6954835):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

The `ItemTemplate` must have fixed dimensions to get a layout like a grid:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
    <StackPanel Width="100" Height="50">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Finally have an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` named `MyItems` where the `MyItem` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has two properties `MyNumber` and `MyText`.

Add your 99 items to the `MyItems` collection and change their `MyText` property as desired.

Comment: I will try it tommorrow and i will come to you with an answer . Thanks a lot !

Comment: WrapPanel doesn't support Virtualization so you might experience performance problems. Just use a ListBox and store your items in a Collection that supports IList.

Comment: If you need virtualization, a solution would be to use a Grid with 9 columns, each containing a VirtualizingStackPanel. Then you'll need 9 collections of MyItem.

Comment: On my first page i want to get a Button "Next" , and the table to be on the second page, and 3th page to be a button , and when u ll press it u will get the answer. How can i do that ?

Comment: If your question about the table is solved, mark it as solved. Your question about buttons and pages is different and should be asked separately (the simplest way is to have multiple panels = your pages inside a single cell grid, and play with panel visibility...)

Comment: Mart can u make for me a snapshot ? I don t understand.

Comment: Please explain what is the part you don't understand. I can edit my response with more details, but I can not make a snapshot as I didn't develop your whole project (and I don't want to).

Comment: The second part, where i need to write <Data template > , and where i must make an ObservableCollection ?

Comment: You usually have a class instance set as the global data context (LayoutRoot.DataContext = MyContext). That class has the member MyItems that is an ObservableCollection<MyItem>. This way ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" finds the right items.